# Почему не работает line-height?

Tags: css

Подскажите, почему для вложенного тега li не работает свойство line-height?

Т.е. для параграфа установлен свой line-height, а для тега li, в котором лежит параграф, нужно установить также line-height, чтобы сделать отступ между тегами li

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
}
._lg-left{
  float:left;
  width: 33,33%;
}
._lg-left li{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  line-height: 70px;
}
p{
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-equipment">
  <li class="_lg-left">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>item1</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>item2</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>item3</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="_lg-left">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>item1</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>item2</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>item3</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Почему бы вам не сделать нужный вам отступ с помощью margin или padding?

Comment: А вообще line-height не работает, потому что он применяется не к блоку, а к содержимому-буковкам, а для буковок действует `line-height` из тега `<p>`